# Convert Map<String, List<String>> to single List<String>?

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning-aura-components, trigger

```
Map<String, List<String>> mapValues; //some values
List<String> listValues;
listValues.addAll(mapValues.values()); // trying to add map values to list
```

I am currently achieving using for loop using map.values(), But I wanted to directly add it to a single list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just keep using the loop, it's the right tool for the job.

Each map key here points to a `List<String>`, so when you call `.values()` you're getting a `List<List<String>>`.

Apex does not have a way to reduce the dimensionality of a nested data structure (i.e. to go from a `List<List<String>>`, a 2-dimensional structure; to a `List<String>`, a 1-dimensional structure). You're going to need to add each list one at a time to your resulting (flattened) list.